# How to overwrite whole partitioned table in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I want to overwrite all partitions in external table, when `insertInto` data. If any partitions not in data, it needs to be deleted.

`saveAsTable` changed table structure, so I can't use it.

I tried using `insertInto` with parameter `overwrite=True`, but old partitions didn't delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Assuming you have a DataFrame with your new data
new_data = ...

table_name = "your_table"
table_path = "path_to_your_table"
new_data.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto(table_name)
spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {table_name}")
```

The `insert into` method with `mode("overwrite")` is used to overwrite the entire table with the new data. To delete partitions not present in the new data, you can use the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` command.

Comment: `mode("overwrite").insertInto(table_name)` overwrite only partitions which in dataframe and don't delete old partitions

Comment: To drop partitions that are not present in the new data

`spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {table_name}")`

You can also drop empty partitions
`spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {table_name} DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (your_partition_column='your_partition_value')")`